# Center text and toggle visibility

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to use html/Javascript to center some text and then toggle it between visible and invisible after a wait time of 3 seconds. I am using 
a function in JS containing `setTimeout()` to change the display properties after 3s. However the text will neither appear nor vertically center although I have tried countless solutions. Here is what I have so far:

```js
function myfunction() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("parent-class").style.display = "table";
  document.getElementById("h3").style.display = "table-cell";
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("h3").style.display = "none";
  }, 3000);
};
myfunction();
```

```css
.parent-class {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.parent-class>h3 {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-class" style="display:none">
  <h3>+</h3>
</div>
```

If I don't set the property "display:none" to the parent class, the text (a cross) appears erroneously on the first page of my program. Not sure where to go from here as it feels like I've tried many display types and element configurations. Please help!

Comment: h3 is NOT the ID of that element - it is a tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName("parent-class")` returns an array of elements (getElement**s**).
`document.getElementById("h3")` will return nothing since there is no ID h3.

To center the text, have you considered flexboxes?

Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fokq0btv/

Moreover, please consider using `document.querySelector` instead of old `document.getElementBy...`

Comment: Thanks! Setting the parent class to "flex" worked like a charm. I also appreciate the pointers on setting up IDs and classes. I'm pretty new to javascript/html.

Comment: Glad I could help! If you don't know very well flexboxes, please read this article: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
Flexboxes are really cool to make great layout easily!

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple of things wrong with your code. One being you weren't getting an element returned by class name, so I've switched it to getElementById. You also had no element with id "h3", and lastly you didn't call myfunction().

```js
function myfunction() {
  document.getElementById("parent-class").style.display = "table";
  document.getElementById("h3").style.display = "table-cell";
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("h3").style.display = "none";
  }, 3000);
};
myfunction();
```

```css
.parent-class {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

#h3 {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent-class" style="display:none">
  <h3 id="h3">+</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: This for pointing these out! This code solved the toggling visibility issue, but ultimately I used the flexboxes suggested by sjahan to center the text. For some reason I had problems with vertical-align:middle.

Answer (score 0):

To get elements by the tag (or any selector) use `document.querySelector()`, and pass in parameter the selector, for example:

```
document.querySelector(".parent-class")
document.querySelector("#example-id")
document.querySelector("h3")
```

And to center the element vertically/horizontally use the following style:

```
.parent-class {
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center; /* horizontal center */
    position: absolute;
    height: 200px; 
    background: #000; /* its a example */
    color: #fff; /* its a example */
}

.parent-class > h3{
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%); /* here is the magic */
}
```

**PS:** The parent must be `absolute` and have a defined height/width, and the two must be `inline-block`

Follow the code working:

```js
function myfunction() {
  document.querySelector(".parent-class").style.display = "inline-block";
  document.querySelector("h3").style.display = "inline-block";
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.querySelector("h3").style.display = "none";
  }, 3000);
};
myfunction();
```

```css
 

/* reset CSS */
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0; 
}

.parent-class {
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center; /* horizontal center */
    position: absolute;
    height: 200px; 
    background: #000; /* its a example */
    color: #fff; /* its a example */
}

.parent-class > h3{
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%); /* here is the magic */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-class" style="display:none">
  <h3>+</h3>
</div>
```